# Append details from a variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function editors(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('some sheet ID');
  var editors = file.getEditors();
  for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
  Logger.log(editors[i].getEmail());
  }
 sheet.appendRow(editors);
}
```

**GOAL**: I am trying to print all the email IDs of the editors into a spreadsheet, but it does not do that.. Can you please tell me how I can append all the email ID's into a sheet.
When I print the above into a spreadsheet it does not print any email ID's just a bunch of numbers and letters.

Comment: If `email IDs` in your question means the email address and you want to append the editor's email addresses to the Spreadsheet, how about modifying from `sheet.appendRow(editors);` to `sheet.appendRow(editors.map(e => e.getEmail()));`? But I'm not sure whether my understanding for your goal is correct. I apologize for this.

Comment: An email Id is also a bunch of numbers and letters. Can you show the result you are getting?